About the definition of integer-valued additive function on the category of modules
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. In Atiyah-MacDonald (chapter 2, right before proposition 2.11), an integer-valued additive function on a class $\mathcal{C}$ of $A$-modules is defined as a function
$$\lambda: \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
such that for any short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow M_0\rightarrow M_1\rightarrow M_2\rightarrow 0$$
one has $$\lambda(M_1)=\lambda(M_0)+\lambda(M_2).$$
From this definition, it easily follows that $\lambda(M\oplus N)=\lambda(M)+\lambda(N).$ What I am not being able to see is that $\lambda(M)=\lambda(N)$ whenever $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic. My idea was to use that if $M\rightarrow N$ is an isomorphism, then we have an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow M\rightarrow N\rightarrow 0,$$
whence $\lambda(M)=\lambda(N)+\lambda(0)$. However, I do not know a priori that $\lambda(0)=0$. Of course, this would follow from the isomorphism invariance, but that is a circular argument.
Can any of these be deduced from the definition? I feel that the answer is yes, because these facts seem to be used implicitly, for example, in the first paragraph of the proof of theorem 11.1 (Hilbert, Serre) in the same book.
Any help is appreciated.

Even though it was possible here to derive that $\lambda$ is an isomorphic invariant, let me mention that in other similar situations this can not be deduced from the property that exact sequences are preserved, and it is just much more natural to add this to the definition of $\lambda$. This is basically the most important thing we demand of an invariant. That exact sequences are preserved comes afterwards.

We know $\lambda(0)=\lambda(0)+\lambda(0)$ by additivity since there is a natural short exact sequence $$0 \to 0 \to 0 \to 0 \to 0,$$ where the maps given are the zero map.
But this is an equation in $\mathbb{Z}$, and we may subtract $\lambda(0)$ from both sides to get $0=\lambda(0)$. From there, you do have an accurate proof that $M\simeq N$ implies $\lambda(M)= \lambda(N)$.

Sorry for nitpicking, but is it actually true that $0=0\oplus 0$? Or is it just $0\cong 0\oplus 0$? Isn't $0\oplus 0$ technically the set ${(0,0)}$?

@JuliusMaximus I suppose that is a small problem for my argument, but one easily avoided. I'll edit.

That was clever! Thank you so much.

@JuliusMaximus No problem! I do think it's a pretty standard argument, e.g. in proving that a group homomorphism sends the identity to the identity. I think your question can be answered directly in that context, by appealing to K-groups and using that an additive function is a group homomorphism from $K_0(\mathcal{C})$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ or something like that.
